# The associated $X$-bundle to a principal $G$-bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

We can assume that everything is over the complex numbers.

Let $ U $ be a scheme and $ G $ an (affine) algebraic group. Let $ \pi: P \rightarrow U $ be a principal $ G $-bundle. Suppose $ X $ is another scheme with an action $ a : G \times X \rightarrow X $ of $ G $ on $ X $. Then one can construct the associated $ X $-bundle on $ U $, denoted $ \eta : P \times_G X \rightarrow U $ and here is where I will be sloppy - the scheme $ P \times_G X $ is constructed as a quotient of $ P \times X $ by the $ G $-action $ g \cdot (p,x) := (pg^{-1}, gx) $ and $ \eta(p,x) = \pi(p) $ is well defined.

A special case of this construction is when $ X = \mathbb{A}(V) $ is the affine space associated to a finite dimensional vector space $ V $ and the action $ a $ gives a representation of $ G $. In that case, we get the associated vector bundle $ P \times_G \mathbb{A}(V) \rightarrow U $.

All this is easy if we were in the category of topological spaces but my question is in the part where I was sloppy: Why does the quotient exist in the category of schemes? Are there some conditions on $ G,X $ that we need to assume beforehand? I know vaguely that from GIT, we can do it if $ G $ is reductive(?), but a complete answer or a reference where this construction is carried out carefully will be appreciated.

Comment: You can always do this at the level of sheaves on, say, the fppf site. What you get is a sheaf $P\times_G X$ on the fppf site of $U$ which is locally isomorphic to $X\to U$. If $X$ is an affine $U$-scheme then it will automatically be representable as affine morphisms satisfy effective descent on the fppf site.

Comment: @AlexYoucis ok, but can you tell me a reference for this point of view?

Comment: I don't think so. Do you agree that $P\times_G X:=\mathcal{F}$ by a sheaf on the fppf site of $U$ with the property that there is an fppf cover $\{U_i\to U\}$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}$ is represented by some affine morphism $Y_i\to U_i$? If so, then the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf follows from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0245 In the special case when $X$ is a group acted on by $G$ via a homomorphism $G\to X$, then $P\times_G X$ is an $X$-torsor, and as $X$ is affine it is automatically represented by a principal homogeneous is contained in Theorem 4.3(a)

Comment: of Milne's book (his *published book*, not the online notes) on etale cohomology.